# SQL JOIN - Selecting only records that meet ALL criteria in a 1-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, join, one-to-many, sybase

This is a sybase database, which follows t-sql syntax (same/similar to MSSQL).

I have 2 tables, cases and insurance.

```
CASES              insurance
-----              ---------
casenum            ins_id
                   date_resolved
                   case_num
```

Each case number has multiple associated insurance entries, and each of these insurance entries has a date resolved field.

What I'm trying to do, is return ONLY case numbers where ALL associated insurance entries have date_resolved = null.
What I'm getting is case numbers and the associated insurance entries that are null.

For example, if a case number has 3 insurance entries, 2 of which have a null date_resolved, but 1 *does* have a value in date_resolved, my query will return the case number because the 2 entries are null.

Here's what I've tried:

```
select casenum
from cases
left join (select date_resolved from insurance where date_resolved is null) ins
on ins.case_num = cases.casenum

select casenum
from cases
inner join insurance on cases.casenum = insurance.case_num
where insurance.date_resolved is null
```

I'm sorry if this is a beginner's mistake, I've searched the board and have found many similar questions, but none that seem to address my problem.

EDIT -
Using one of the answers provided below, I incorporated it into my query and ended up with something like this (which I believe, works):

```
select casenum, *other stuff*
from cases
inner join (select i.case_num from insurance i group by i.case_num having max(date_resolved) is null) ins
on ins.case_num = cases.casenum
where *other stuff from cases table*
and *more stuff from cases table*
```

I really appreciate it!

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match your query.  For instance, `case_num` is in only one table.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake- yes insurance table has a case_num column, that's how they're joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
select i.case_num
from insurance i
group by i.case_num
having max(date_resolved) is null;
```

Or, you can use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from cases c
where not exists (select 1
                  from insurance i
                  where i.case_num = c.case_num and i.date_resolved is not null
                 );
```

Note that these are *not* equivalent.  The second returns `cases` that have no rows in `insurance`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I incorporated your first example into the sub-query of my first example (but with an inner join), and it seems to be returning the desired results. 
I appreciate it!